# How to manipulate Instant to add two days and string based time?

Tags: java

Assume the following code:

```
Instant x = Instant.now();
System.out.println(x);
```

Yields...

```
2019-05-29T00:19:02.245315Z
```

I would like to add two days, but with time specifically 13:30:00.000000Z without string parsing - using the Java8 time libraries, so the output would look like

```
2019-05-31T13:30:00.000000Z
```

The time portion 13:30:00.000000Z is a configuration item stored as a string.  How to specify this time portion using the string data and not parsing it into hour, minute, and second variables first?

Is this possible or do I need to do string parsing?

**Edit**

My question was about 30 minutes old and closed as a duplicate.  I reviewed the duplicate and found while it does allow specifying a time it does not allow specifying a time as a string.  I will answer my own question here in the question body instead of adding the answer as an answer since I can no longer answer a closed question...

I would have awarded points to @wizard because he gave me the clue how to build the result I desired...

```
Instant scheduledDate = LocalDate.now().plusDays(2).atStartOfDay().plusSeconds(LocalTime.parse("13:30:00").toSecondOfDay()).atZone(ZoneId.of("UTC")).toInstant();
```

yeilds...

```
2019-05-30T13:30:00Z
```

Comment: `LocalDate.now().plusDays(2).atStartOfDay()` may be?

Comment: 1)  Instant xPlusTwoDays = x.plus(2, ChronoUnit.DAYS);

Comment: @Wizard - thanks for the help - you provided the insight I needed with .plusDays(), and with .atStartOfDay().  Thanks!